# What is the Awaited Type in TypeScript

Tags: typescript, types

In the recent version of TypeScript 4.5, there is a new type called [Awaited](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/utility-types.html#awaitedtype). It looks like this type is for handling promises. I found this is not well described in the documentation and I did not find any better examples of it anywhere.

Can someone please explain what this type is for and how it works?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: [This documentation](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-4-5.html#the-awaited-type-and-promise-improvements) doesn't suffice for you?  I'm not sure how much extra information you need; if you write `const x = await y`, then the type of `x` will be `Awaited<typeof y>`.  It recursively unwaps `Promise`s, because if you `await` a `string` or a `Promise<string>` or a `Promise<Promise<string>>` or a `Promise<Promise<Promise<string>>>`, you will get a `string`, so `Awaited<>` returns `string` for all those types.

Comment: Does that fully address the question or are you looking for something else?  If that meets your needs I could write it up as an answer with sources; otherwise, what am I missing?

Comment: I think it is one of those types that are more like operators, like `Extract`. It is useful if you work with types of generic Promises.

Comment: ^ I haven't actually answered yet, I just commented; if you want me to write an actual answer I can, although @Evert's answer is essentially the same in spirit (although it lacks sources, someone could edit that in if they want)

Comment: Are you planning to give an answer @jcalz?

Comment: Okay, sure, why not?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

If you're looking for more detailed and explanatory documentation for [the `Awaited<T>` utility type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/utility-types.html#awaitedtype), you might want to look at [the relevant section of the TypeScript 4.5 release notes](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-4-5.html#the-awaited-type-and-promise-improvements) and the implementing pull request [microsoft/TypeScript#45350](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/pull/45350).

The goal of `Awaited<T>` is to describe the (perhaps surprisingly) complicated type operation represented by `await` in an `async` function.  When you `await` a value of some type `T`, you will get a value of type `Awaited<T>`:

```
async function foo<T>(x: T) {
    const y = await x;
    // const y: Awaited<T> in TS4.5 and above 
    // (just T in TS4.4 and below)
}
```

If the type `T` of the you are `await`ing isn't a `Promise` of any kind, then `Awaited<T>` is just the same as `T`:

```
async function bar(x: string) {
    const y = await x;
    // const y: string
    // Awaited<string> is just string
}
```

If the type `T` you are `await`ing is a `Promise<U>` where `U` isn't a `Promise` of any kind, then `Awaited<T>` is the same as `U`:

```
async function baz(x: Promise<string>) {
    const y = await x;
    // const y: string
    // Awaited<Promise<string>> is just string
}
```

Things become more complicated when the type `T` you are `await`ing is a `Promise<Promise<V>>`; if `V` isn't a `Promise`, then `Awaited<T>` is the same as `V`:

```
async function qux(x: Promise<Promise<string>>) {
    const y = await x;
    // const y: string
}
```

That's because `await` *recursively unwraps* any `Promise`s until it hits a non-`Promise` (or some awful error condition, like a non-promise object with a `then()` method); you should never get a `Promise` out of an `await`:

```
async function quux(x: Promise<Promise<Promise<Promise<string>>>>) {
    const y = await x;
    // const y: string
}
```

So that means `Awaited<T>` also recursively unwraps promises, via the following [recursive conditional type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-4-1.html#recursive-conditional-types):

```
/**
 * Recursively unwraps the "awaited type" of a type. 
   Non-promise "thenables" should resolve to `never`. 
   This emulates the behavior of `await`.
 */
type Awaited<T> =
    T extends null | undefined ? T : // special case for `null | undefined` 
                                     // when not in `--strictNullChecks` mode
        T extends object & { then(onfulfilled: infer F, ...args: infer _): any } ? 
        // `await` only unwraps object types with a callable `then`. 
        // Non-object types are not unwrapped
            F extends ((value: infer V, ...args: infer _) => any) ? 
            // if the argument to `then` is callable, extracts the first argument
                Awaited<V> : // recursively unwrap the value
                never : // the argument to `then` was not callable
        T; // non-object or non-thenable
```

It also handles [union types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#union-types); for example, if you have something which is *either* a `string` *or* a `Promise<number>` and `await` it, then you will get *either* a `string` *or* a `number` out:

```
async function union(x: string | Promise<number>) {
    const y = await x;
    // const y: string | number
}
```

And so on with recursively wrapped unions:

```
async function wha(x: number | Promise<string | Promise<number | Promise<Promise<boolean>>>>) {
    const y = await x;
    // const y: string | number | boolean
}
```

Before TypeScript 4.5 the above `await`s mostly worked, but there were some glitches, especially around the behavior of `Promise`-combination methods like [`Promise.all()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/all):

```
async function oops(x1: Promise<string | Promise<number>>, x2: Promise<string | Promise<number>>) {
    const y = await Promise.all([x1, x2]);
    // const y: [string | Promise<number>, string | Promise<number>] in TS4.4 and below 
    // const y: [string | number, string | number] in TS4.5 and above 
}
```

---

So the `Awaited<T>` type was introduced in order to more fully handle the effects of `Promise` manipulation, in the face of some weird edge cases that people had reported as bugs (which you can see in microsoft/TypeScript#45350).

In practice you probably don't need to deal with it much yourself, but it's helpful that it exists.

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=4.9.4#code/HYQwtgpgzgDiDGEAEANJBvAsAKAJABcBPGZAQQHcQBLfCAEwB4AVAPiQF4ddcmkIAPWsDpQkwAK4AbSUgA+SccIgAzKsHpIA-El4AuJAHoDSWBHhUQM+CCjJlAewBOSAAYTpchUtXq6LpFy4RkjkABYQwGL2+EhqrgC08VD4jlTw+AByUpIAwuHwANZQ-mD2dBCBvAJCIkj2AEYAVmYxAGQYSPjhwAAU9sDKUqrS9PpqyhDOAGIANEgAdIsgjgDmUGMDk0gA+gCU+iDAhEgAvlqBwS4glDT+-ZLHiuSOIDCiDc3pncTQITShSBASGs0hA9UkyBcXQiLnmATwQWMGX68Q+LW+JFEy2QwGiXmerxIdECUz4ggitR6PQAbpZxBANhNnAA1OaLebLNaMrZ7DhsQ6EXbnBHBKjKTrhQGrcSQYAxfD2VzQ4D+KiiEGSMEQubVF7pUTQpCqRzJKUrGURfCBCjUWiMZlsfTBRxmcQmqjUiAPfEvGAS5C0yT0wLqT3OJ3GQ2ci1yzqKqHdfyUUS4mIarUVBFMADchmMuOAqKa6KcUULyozOCr2BO1ZshGA8CNinSVH6Rvs9mYLB6-H0TCFWDw8H6puO7EBNxi-GzXGCI+AY-0Npo9G7c+MC6XOiQ9RUTmQTAAygAWeYAVhwtewOHrjebjfwbci9WWvf0yVSwBWg64W5i46TraSAzhuwKjgBH4pGoKxXnWUANk2gyPs+u4gAAXu+SAAAqOPYYBqhADCfjBLC-sOEFIIB1zAaBeDzpRhBQV+sF4Pw8zKj0frsGwMAcfYACqMAkI4OQ2BAPS7LscE3tgd5IS2T7tgAjuI-BYbh+GEQwmkEbYxHQd+LBkRgf6MRwQE0CBs70ZujHMTBMnwYhD6tip4hqRpeF6URunaX5+kBURJFGcZJlDrg-5URZNFWXRiLgYukEmIZrHXreCH3shbmRIoz5YSFKyeEFDASGAe6OOFZlJdFE6xdONkJVFTEpSxnhlRVTlyZlCkoe2YQgFhHVbPIJWFcV3nacNzijZNgVzUR9SdhChxhVVFE1dRU7WWBzUOd+7UyhVnhLfYK3AF18muUpkSdm8vYAIz6GNqUTVp+nTcZcz8AATM9C0GW1s3vURn3rZF5l1dtQUctIPQANr8A930-QAursNlIFjeaJdu8PjcDPmlUdkwsHMBM4QDn2o7EkTHmeJ6AsIu5evY5BIIAvBuALR7u32Ug+OvfI03k4LYgk44NNxPTF5M3QgJLZ6nOAFB7V5AA)

Answer (score 12):

The short version is that given `Awaited<X>`, you will get:

```
X - If X was not a promise,
Y - If X was Promise<Y>
Z - If X had the type Promise<Promise<Z>>
```

So:

```
Awaited<number>  -> Gives you number
Awaited<Promise<string>> -> Gives you string 
Awaited<Promise<Promise<boolean>>> -> Gives you boolean
```

The idea is that in Javascript you can await non-promises and just get the same value back:

```
const x = await 5; // x = 5
```

The examples above were already somewhat possible before `Awaited` was introduced, but it gets weird when promise types are nested like `Promise<Promise<Y>>`, so the tl;dr is:

The `Awaited<X>` type is what you get when you `await` something with type `X`. In other words, it removes any number of `Promise` wrappers. (or more specifically, `PromiseLike`).

Comment: In addition, it indicates that  that you should handle it with try/error rather than then() and catch()

Comment: That assumes `X` is not a `Promise` itself, I suppose?

Comment: @jcalz, I added some clarification about nested promises.

Comment: Not necessarily, because you can also handle promises with try catch as long as the promise function is called with `await`

Comment: @MichaelBrenndoerfer What you're saying sounds like a related concept but not sure exactly how it applies here.

Comment: In your block at the top you say `Awaited<X>  -> Gives you the type X`, but that's only true if `X` is not itself a `Promise` type.

Comment: @jcalz I made my examples less ambigious, hope that clarifies things

Comment: I guess?  It works for `X` but now what you're saying about `Y` and `Z` are still not necessarily true because you have not said that `Y` and `Z` are non-promises.  I think it's clear what you *mean*, but the whole point of `Awaited` is that it will unwrap all levels of nested promises, so saying "`Awaited<Promise<Promise<Y>>>` is `Y`" cannot be known to be true unless `Y` is known not to be a promise.  Using concrete examples like `string`  avoids this issue because we know `string` is not a promise.  But I don't know what `Y` and `Z` are.

Comment: @jcalz The imporant thing is what you know what I mean, especially with the additional context. If you're looking for a perfect reference, you might like the documentation better.